# What’s wrong with my succulent?

Tags: diagnosis

whats wrong with my succulent? Am I watering too much? Too much sun? My cat maybe? Help!

(It gets indirect sunlight everyday, and I keep a calendar of when I water so it’s not excessive) 
[image]

Comment: Can you add another photo showing the whole plant please? Its difficult to decide quite what the plant is with just this slightly out of focus close up... How much sun does it get during a day? I'm assuming this is a houseplant and not outdoors?

Comment: It looks like mechanical damage to the leaves. I would suspect the cat also.